# Replace all html tag attributes with regex

Tags: python, html, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out how can I add attribute `id=ID_<number>` to all tags in `html` snippet and remove another attributes.

For example:

```
<div class="...">...</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="DIV_1">...</div>
```

The `DIV` is a tag name in uppercase and _1 means ordering. So if this `<div>` would be a second tag, it would have `DIV_2` id. The ordering is in DFS meaning so if the `<div id="DIV_2">..</div>` has some child like `<div id="DIV_2"><ul class=".." style="..">...</ul></div>`, the `ul` tag would have id: `UL_3`.

I tried to find all tags and then, remove their attributes and one by one add them their ID's.

`re.findall(r'<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>',snippet)`

This finds all tags. My idea is like:

```
for i,tag in enumerate(tags):

    remove_all_attributes_from_tag
    get name of the tag and add set attribute "{}_{}".format(tag_name.upper,i)
```

But can't figure out how to continue.

The snippet:

```
<div id="wtab" class="pd_cont" style="display: table;"><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Display</h4><span>5.20-inch</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Processor</h4><span>2GHz octa-core</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Front Camera</h4><span>8-megapixel</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Resolution</h4><span>1080x1920 pixels</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>RAM</h4><span>3GB</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>OS</h4><span>Android 6.0</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Storage</h4><span>32GB</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Rear Camera</h4><span>16-megapixel</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Battery Capacity</h4><span>2650mAh</span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace all tag attributes with the id structure and a unique identifier. In a second step replace the unique identifier one by one in a loop.

**Code**

```
import re
html_orig = '<div id="wtab" class="pd_cont" style="display: table;"><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Display</h4><span>5.20-inch</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Processor</h4><span>2GHz octa-core</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Front Camera</h4><span>8-megapixel</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Resolution</h4><span>1080x1920 pixels</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>RAM</h4><span>3GB</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>OS</h4><span>Android 6.0</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Storage</h4><span>32GB</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Rear Camera</h4><span>16-megapixel</span></div><div class="pd_colmn"><h4>Battery Capacity</h4><span>2650mAh</span></div></div>'
html_edit = re.sub('(<[\w\d]+)(\s?[\w\d\s=;"_:]*)(>)',
                   '\g<1> id="DIV_!id!\g<3>', html_orig)
i = 1
while True:
    sub = re.subn('!id!', str(i), html_edit, count=1)
    if sub[1] == 0:
        break
    html_edit = sub[0]
    i += 1
```

[`re.subn()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn) returns a tuple including the number of subs, this enables the break condition for the loop.

**Result**

```
'<div id="DIV_1><div id="DIV_2><h4 id="DIV_3>Display</h4><span id="DIV_4>5.20-inch</span></div><div id="DIV_5><h4 id="DIV_6>Processor</h4><span id="DIV_7>2GHz octa-core</span></div><div id="DIV_8><h4 id="DIV_9>Front Camera</h4><span id="DIV_10>8-megapixel</span></div><div id="DIV_11><h4 id="DIV_12>Resolution</h4><span id="DIV_13>1080x1920 pixels</span></div><div id="DIV_14><h4 id="DIV_15>RAM</h4><span id="DIV_16>3GB</span></div><div id="DIV_17><h4 id="DIV_18>OS</h4><span id="DIV_19>Android 6.0</span></div><div id="DIV_20><h4 id="DIV_21>Storage</h4><span id="DIV_22>32GB</span></div><div id="DIV_23><h4 id="DIV_24>Rear Camera</h4><span id="DIV_25>16-megapixel</span></div><div id="DIV_26><h4 id="DIV_27>Battery Capacity</h4><span id="DIV_28>2650mAh</span></div></div>'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works almost perfectly. Just one thing. If there is for example id="wtab-8585" instead of id="wtab", it starts to replace IDS from the second tag. <div id="wtab-8585" class="pd_cont" style="display: table;"><div id="DIV_1><h4 id="DIV_2>Display<...